# Explanation for group by 3 elements from a list function using FOLD in OCAML

Tags: recursion, ocaml, fold

I have a piece of code that does the following: group 3 elements of a list of n elements. The main function is called `group_by_3`. For example, executing group_by_3 `[1;2;3;4;5;6;7]` will give me `([1;2;3],[4;5;6],[7])`.

```
let group_by_3 lst =
  let accum = ( [], [], 0 )
  in
  let f (all_groups, current_group, size) x =
    if size = 3
    then ( (List.rev current_group) :: all_groups, 
           [x], 1 )
    else ( all_groups, x::current_group, size+1)
  in
  let (groups, last, _) = List.fold_left f accum lst
  in List.rev ( List.rev last :: groups)
```

I don't really understand why this works (it is provided in class).

- What are all_groups, current_group, size?
- What does this do?

  ```
  if size = 3
  then ( (List.rev current_group) :: all_groups, 
         [x], 1 )
  else ( all_groups, x::current_group, size+1)
  ```

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

> What are `all_groups`, `current_group`, `size`?

These are the three pieces of *state* required to produce the groupings by visiting each item in the input sequence. These individual states are combined in a 3-tuple to form a single state for the fold. Ultimately we'll only care about `all_groups`, and the other two are just intermediate state necessary to construct that.

- `all_groups`: This is a list value that accretes completed groupings. Whenever we've seen enough new elements to satisfy the group size, we make a new group and add it to this list.
- `current_group`: This is also a list value, but more of a temporary buffer to build up a grouping until it reaches `size`. When it's big enough, it gets added to `all_groups` and is reset to a new group/list with the current item `[x]`.
- `size` this is just a counter to track how many items are in `current_group`.

> What does this do?

`if size = 3` simply decides whether we want to keep accumulating elements or if we've got enough for a grouping.

`then ( (List.rev current_group) :: all_groups, [x], 1 )` is building/returning the new accumulator value, which is a 3-tuple of `all_groups`, `current_group`, and `size`. The `List.rev` call is necessary because of the way the list is being grown, in the *else* branch; it's fastest to add items to the *front* of a list, but this is the *reverse* of the input sequence thus we reverse them. `x` is the current item, which will be the first item in the new, growing group. `1` is of course the size of that new group.

`else ( all_groups, x::current_group, size+1)` is popping the current item `x` onto the front of the `current_group` list and incrementing the `size` counter.

Below that section is the logic that takes care of any straggler items that don't fit neatly into groupings of three.